# Under which circumstances does GDB enable background processing?

Tags: debugging, gdb

I am currently developing a wrapper library in order to start GDB from my application and have it debug a program.

I am using MinGW32 since I am working with the Ada Gnat compiler which is only available in 32 bit on windows. My OS is windows Server 2008R2 64 bit.

I can not start an application in the debugger in the background with "run&". GDB reports that background processing is not available on my configuration.

I am relatively new to GDB and it is my understanding, and my tests confirm this, that I can not send new commands to GDB while the debugg is running and is not in background mode. That means that I can not interrupt the debuggee or in other words, if I forget to set a breakpoint, there is no way to interrupt it, set a breakpoint and continue. Unless it runs in background mode which means GDB accepts commands while the debuggee is running.

My question is: Is this generally so on Windows or does it come from my particular setup? 
On which systems should background processing be available?

Comment: Not on Linux. BTW: What would running an application in background accomplish? Have you looked into GDB/MI (https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/GDB_002fMI.html)?

Comment: Yes, I'm using that book to write my code, thanks. I updated my question to include the answer, perhaps I was not clear enough about my reasons

Comment: You can interrupt it. In command mode it's via CTRL+c, when controlled via MI I guess you need to send a signal. Then you can set additional breakpoints and resume.

Comment: Well under windows you cant really send signals. I tried the only function that's available under windows, cant remember the name right now, but it allows you to send Ctr-C and a break signal to a console only, none of it worked. I think the signal mechanism isn't implement very well on Windows

Comment: Eclipse definitely can suspend gdb on user request even on Windows. You can check the source (I don't have it here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Background processing requires the "target-async" feature, which is only implemented by the remote and Linux native targets.  So, if your gdb is using gdbserver, it may work.  Porting a target to be async-capable is not very hard in most cases, but nobody has ever done this work for the Windows native target.

Note that the other comments are correct, though.  There's some way to interrupt gdb when using MI on Windows.  Unfortunately I am not a Windows expert and I don't know what that is.  Nevertheless you don't need target-async to do this.

Comment: Ok thanks, that helps at least somewhat. I was pretty sure it's not possible on Windows because the background run didnt work, but I now I will at least continue to search for a way